# Suggested edits do not save in tag wiki edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, editor

If you make a suggested edit to a question or an answer, and then you decide that it needs further editing, the edit box saves what you had already suggested, even if it hasn't been approved yet. That really helps.

However, after fat-fingering and having to submit a few replacement edits on English.SE, I realized that this doesn't happen for tag wikis. In other words, the edit box fails to retain your suggested edit and instead displays the pre-approval status of the change. Could we get the tag wiki editor to also retain suggested edits?

This, of course, doesn't affect other editors, since only the original editor is allowed to make a change while the suggested edit is sitting in the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great find - this will be pushed either tonight or tomorrow.